# TalkBack: accessibility: sound cues instead of all text being read, in order to speed up everything

Tags: accessibility, open-source, talk-back, custom-sounds

I am using Android on a Realme 6 phone.

When reading interface elements out with TalkBack, it wastes a lot of time reading out what is on the screen as I explore by touch or use linear navigation.

It would be nice if TalkBack had a feature where you could switch back and forth between normal mode and another "quick cue" mode.

In this quick cue mode, when TalkBack encounters an element, it plays a very brief sound corresponding to the type of widget encountered. The user learns to recognize these sounds and can browse quickly through the interface without being distracted, closer to how a seeing user of the interface would.

When the user wants to know what type of element the sound corresponds to, the user swipes left then up then right, to be reminded. Otherwise scrolls quickly till they get to what they want, quickly building a mental idea of what's there.

To read out the text of a button, since the sound cue alone is played out, the user swipes right then up the left. The button text, which takes longer to be read out, is then read aloud. Or the user can switch back to normal mode and proceed.

The sound cues may correspond to things like "time", "share button", "tool button", "add button", "modify button", "delete button", "done button", "submit button", "text widget", "caption", "text entry widget", and so on. Markup, following a given markup XML prefix for the standard set of standardized sounds included, would be supplied, and available in the source code to support this, for the benefit of these very blind users so that they may be able to hear these standard assigned cues for faster less stressful browsing in TalkBack than I'd text would have to be read out everywhere.

Many times when we view a time widget we don't read the time out. Similarly, when viewing a share button, we don't read out "share" to ourselves, we simply recognize the button. With a sound cue, the non-seeing users experience corresponds more closely to a seeing user's experience. This would thus enhance the blind user's ability to use a variety of apps, including apps that were designed primarily for seeing users, but that included blind user support. Perhaps, in many cases, a separate interface should be designed and made accessible to blind users in apps. However, it is not guaranteed that developers would do this, although it would only be right if they were pushed to do this through development tools, and, in this case, how would a blind user access the separate blind user-specific interface to the given apps supporting this feature.

There could be a special swipe gesture in TalkBack to switch between normal mode and quick cue mode. For instance, up then right then down, or up then left then down.

Does TalkBack currently support such a behavior, or does anyone know whether Google and Android have plans to support this behavior for blind users in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that all your question about Android for blind people would get more response/answers in a disabled community than in an Android community. The number of disabled people or their friends using Stackexchange seems to be very low therefore you don't get any answers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please point me to any disabled community sites, linked to software development and not? Thanks.

Comment: That is the point it seems nobody here seems to be affected (or those don't want or can answer) and thus do know such a community. So i can't help you on this. There is Google, Facebook, Twitter and whatever you can use to find or ask on for such a community.